# Convert Raw SQL Query to Laravel Eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent

My project is a content management system & a new version of it will be integrated in a Laravel framework; and there are lots of huge SQL queries which needs to be converted into eloquent syntax.

I found the following [tool](https://laravel-news.com/convert-sql-laravel-builder-orator) to convert my already written queries into eloquent syntax, but it does not work.

Could anyone guide me to convert my queries or help me find a tool that could do the job?

Please find below a sample of my queries (note that most of my queries look similar):

```
SELECT id, name, code,
       ( SELECT price FROM productprice WHERE id = p.id ) AS price,
       ( SELECT image FROM productpictures WHERE id = p.id LIMIT 1 ) 
AS image
FROM product p 
WHERE categoryid = 1
```

Thank you.

Comment: If you want to use the ORM then you need to create the models extending Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model and set the proper relations. Or you can use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder to use fluent interfaces or standard SQL syntax. which approach are you going to use ?

Comment: Is there any tool online for converting large queries?

Comment: As mentioned previously : the laravel docs are the best tool. Link: https://laravel.com/docs/master/queries

You can't expect to develop something well if you do not understand it. Eloquent is simple for anyone who knows MySQL, easier in many cases.

Comment: I know eloquent. I posted this question to not help with the quires. I asked that i have lots of big sql queries and it will take time to convert them in eloquent. I asked is there a way to convert queries faster?

Comment: How big is big? I have worked on statements that have been potentially 100's of lines. In some of those cases, it may not be best to use eloquent. You need to make a decision. I highly doubt you will find a converter for anything more complex than a simple SQL string or it will probably have a lot of errors in that you probably spend more time fixing than just doing it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Really your SQL should be using joins like so :

```
SELECT 
p.id,
p.name,
p.code,
pprice.price,
ppictures.image
FROM product p
LEFT JOIN productprice pprice on p.id = pprice.id
LEFT JOIN productpictures ppictures on p.id = ppictures.id
WHERE p.categoryid = 1;
```

You can read more [here](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-left-join.aspx) about left joins.

Also its probably not advisory to match ID's like that, it would be better to have a product_id on the productpictures and productprices and then you can have a foreign key constraint on that to the products table.

But alas that is not the question. To make this into laravel eloquent you should use [relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships) and then you can simply do something like this:

```
$Product = Product::select('id', 'name', 'code')
->with('ProductPrice', 'ProductPictures')
->where('categoryid', 1)
->get();
```

and you will be able to pull that out like so:

```
$Product->id;
$Product->name;
$Product->code;
$Product->ProductPrice->price;
$Product->ProductPicture->image;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use this [online tool](http://cryptic-peak-77605.herokuapp.com/) to convert the SQL query to Laravel Builder.

And converted query should display in Laravel Builder :

```
DB::select(`id`,`name`,`code`)
    ->selectSub(`SELECT price FROM productprice WHERE id = p.id`, `price`)
    ->selectSub(`SELECT image FROM productpictures WHERE id = p.id LIMIT 1`, `image`)
    ->from(`product as p`)
    ->where(`categoryid`, `=`, 1)
    ->get();
```